# Two vector spaces with homeomorphic open subsets are isomorphic?

Tags: vector-spaces, banach-spaces

Is it true that if $ E,F$ are two topological vector spaces (or say Banach spaces) over $\mathbb{R}$ such that they have nonempty open subsets $U\subset E, V\subset F$ which are homeomorphic, then the two vector spaces are isomorphic? If false, then what can we say if the two open subsets are $\mathcal{C}^1$-diffeomorphic?

Comment: There's a [famous result](http://testuvannya.com.ua/M.I.Kadets/PDF/K-1967-1.pdf) that states any two separable infinite dimensional Banach spaces are topologically homeomorphic.

Comment: Thanks, I have got the answer from MathOverflow : http://mathoverflow.net/questions/219644/two-vector-spaces-with-homeomorphic-open-subsets-are-isomorphic